sending custom email to customers after a configured time from the order procced time
I'm attempting to configure a plugin that sends an email to the customer after they place or complete an order. The plugin should send a custom email after a specified time, but for some reason, the email is neither sent nor received. i wrote coded some input and addtionnal checks in place so i confirm eveything in place , other email like order procced the sutomer recieve them normally without any problem at all
I'm trying to set up a plugin that should send a custom email to the customer after they place or complete an order. However, I've encountered an issue where the email is not being sent or received as expected. I've added some input and additional checks to ensure that everything is in place, and other emails such as order confirmations are being received by the customer without any issues.
 public function schedule_review_email($order_id, $old_status, $new_status) {
        $settings = get_option('fast_reviews_settings');
    
        if (!$settings || empty($settings['trigger_status']) || empty($settings['send_after_value']) || empty($settings['send_after_unit'])) {
            error_log("Fast Reviews settings are not properly configured.");
            return;
        }
    
        error_log("schedule_review_email triggered for Order ID: $order_id, Old Status: $old_status, New Status: $new_status");
    
        if ($new_status === $settings['trigger_status']) {
            $delay = intval($settings['send_after_value']);
            $unit = sanitize_text_field($settings['send_after_unit']);
    
            $valid_units = ['seconds', 'minutes', 'hours', 'days'];
            if (!in_array($unit, $valid_units)) {
                error_log("Invalid time unit provided: $unit");
                return;
            }
    
            $unit_multiplier = $unit === 'seconds' ? 1 : ($unit === 'minutes' ? 60 : ($unit === 'hours' ? 3600 : 86400));
            $schedule_timestamp = time() + $delay * $unit_multiplier;
    
            error_log("Scheduling email for Order ID: $order_id to be sent after $delay $unit at timestamp: $schedule_timestamp");
    
            wp_clear_scheduled_hook('fast_reviews_send_email', [$order_id]);
    
            wp_schedule_single_event($schedule_timestamp, 'fast_reviews_send_email', [$order_id]);
        } else {
            error_log("No action taken for Order ID: $order_id. New status does not match trigger status.");
        }
    }
    
    public function send_review_email($order_id) {
        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
        if (!$order) {
            error_log("Order not found for Order ID: $order_id");
            return;
        }
    
        $customer_name = $order->get_billing_first_name();
        $order_number = $order->get_order_number();
        $customer_email = $order->get_billing_email();
    
        if (empty($customer_email)) {
            error_log("No billing email found for Order ID: $order_id");
            return;
        }
    
        error_log("Preparing to send review email for Order ID: $order_id, Customer Name: $customer_name, Order Number: $order_number");
    
        // Retrieve email settings
        $settings = get_option('fast_reviews_settings');
        if (!$settings) {
            error_log("Fast Reviews settings not found.");
            return;
        }
    
        $review_url = isset($settings['review_url']) ? esc_url($settings['review_url']) : '';
        $trustpilot_url = isset($settings['trustpilot_url']) ? esc_url($settings['trustpilot_url']) : '';
        $subject = isset($settings['email_subject']) ? sanitize_text_field($settings['email_subject']) : 'Review Request';
        $content = isset($settings['email_content']) ? str_replace(
            ['{customer_name}', '{order_number}', '{review_url}', '{trustpilot_url}'],
            [$customer_name, $order_number, $review_url, $trustpilot_url],
            wpautop($settings['email_content']) // Convert line breaks to HTML <p> tags
        ) : '';
    
        $headers = [
            'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8',
            'From: Your Company Name <noreply@yourdomain.com>', // Customize From address
            'Reply-To: support@yourdomain.com' // Customize Reply-To address
        ];
    
        $max_attempts = 3;
        $sent = false;
    
        for ($attempts = 1; $attempts <= $max_attempts; $attempts++) {
            error_log("Attempt $attempts: Sending email to: $customer_email, Subject: $subject");
    
            $sent = wp_mail($customer_email, $subject, $content, $headers);
    
            if ($sent) {
                error_log("Email sent successfully to: $customer_email");
                break; 
            } else {
                error_log("Attempt $attempts: Failed to send email to: $customer_email");
                if ($attempts < $max_attempts) {
                    sleep(5); 
                }
            }
        }


Your current provided code is incomplete to understand why you are facing this issue. Edit your question providing the necessary required code, to be able to reproduce the problem.

So it's tough to say based on the code provided, we don't see where theses functions are being used... I'm going to assume that schedule_review_email is on an order complete hook of some sort. IF that's the case, the first thing that jumps out at me is where you call wp_schedule_single_event, the second parameter is a function name. I assume the second function is the one you want to run? Those function names don't match. Could be the problem? I'm making lots of assumptions here though, tough to say without more info.
